# Pyspark, how to append a dataframe but remove duplicates from a specific one

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am retrieving data from a source once a day, but due to some delays I need to retrieve data a little further back than the most recent from the previous retrieval. This causes some overlap and what I am trying to achieve is to drop the rows in the old dataframe that has timestamp that are in the new dataframe so that I only keep the most recently retrieved inforrmation.

An example of the data:

```py
df_old.show()

+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|              index|                 A|                 B|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|2013-01-01 00:00:00| 6.251379599223777| 10.23320055553287|
|2013-01-01 00:10:00| 6.245690342672945| 10.22296550603164|
|2013-01-01 00:20:00|6.2534029157968956|10.221452136599193|
|2013-01-01 00:30:00| 6.247532408988978|10.212423634472028|
|2013-01-01 00:40:00| 6.253508510989639|10.194494950388954|
|2013-01-01 00:50:00| 6.247517363773414|10.200814690766375|
|2013-01-01 01:00:00|  6.25381864046542|10.192425005184585|
|2013-01-01 01:10:00| 6.250060498528904|10.181246688945123|
|2013-01-01 01:20:00| 6.254461614739839| 10.18021442155982|
|2013-01-01 01:30:00| 6.233226501275796|10.180681886095698|
|2013-01-01 01:40:00| 6.252799353320566|10.169008765187861|
|2013-01-01 01:50:00| 6.248423707837854| 10.16567354928804|
|2013-01-01 02:00:00| 6.253744374163072|10.161773904107136|
|2013-01-01 02:10:00| 6.238242597088755|10.151641862402213|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+


df_new.show()

+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|              index|                 A|                 B|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|2013-01-01 01:30:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 01:40:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 01:50:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 02:00:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 02:10:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 02:20:00|  6.24546611958182| 10.14886792741417|
|2013-01-01 02:30:00| 6.240802043802097| 10.15267232231782|
|2013-01-01 02:40:00| 6.249921473522189|10.139161473568803|
|2013-01-01 02:50:00|6.2219054718011515| 10.11521891469772|
|2013-01-01 03:00:00| 6.247084671443932|10.088592826542145|
|2013-01-01 03:10:00|  6.24950717588649|10.065343892142995|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

And what I want to achieve is this result where only the overlapping results from the new df is kept:

```py
df_combined.show()

+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|              index|                 A|                 B|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|2013-01-01 00:00:00| 6.251379599223777| 10.23320055553287|
|2013-01-01 00:10:00| 6.245690342672945| 10.22296550603164|
|2013-01-01 00:20:00|6.2534029157968956|10.221452136599193|
|2013-01-01 00:30:00| 6.247532408988978|10.212423634472028|
|2013-01-01 00:40:00| 6.253508510989639|10.194494950388954|
|2013-01-01 00:50:00| 6.247517363773414|10.200814690766375|
|2013-01-01 01:00:00|  6.25381864046542|10.192425005184585|
|2013-01-01 01:10:00| 6.250060498528904|10.181246688945123|
|2013-01-01 01:20:00| 6.254461614739839| 10.18021442155982|
|2013-01-01 01:30:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 01:40:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 01:50:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 02:00:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 02:10:00| 7                | 20               |
|2013-01-01 02:20:00|  6.24546611958182| 10.14886792741417|
|2013-01-01 02:30:00| 6.240802043802097| 10.15267232231782|
|2013-01-01 02:40:00| 6.249921473522189|10.139161473568803|
|2013-01-01 02:50:00|6.2219054718011515| 10.11521891469772|
|2013-01-01 03:00:00| 6.247084671443932|10.088592826542145|
|2013-01-01 03:10:00|  6.24950717588649|10.065343892142995|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Are there any easy built-in functions that can achieve this result?

Comment: what about `df_new.union(df_old)`?

Comment: @Lamanus When I use `df_new.union(df_old)` it return both the new and the old values. To give an exterme example, if you had two identical dataframes each with 10 rows then the resulting dataframe would have 20 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `outer` join.

```
df1.join(df2, ['index'], 'outer') \
  .select('index', coalesce(df2.A, df1.A), coalesce(df2.B, df1.B)).toDF('index', 'A', 'B') \
  .orderBy('index').show(20, False)

+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|index              |A                 |B                 |
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|2013-01-01 00:00:00|6.251379599223777 |10.23320055553287 |
|2013-01-01 00:10:00|6.245690342672945 |10.22296550603164 |
|2013-01-01 00:20:00|6.2534029157968956|10.221452136599193|
|2013-01-01 00:30:00|6.247532408988978 |10.212423634472028|
|2013-01-01 00:40:00|6.253508510989639 |10.194494950388954|
|2013-01-01 00:50:00|6.247517363773414 |10.200814690766375|
|2013-01-01 01:00:00|6.25381864046542  |10.192425005184585|
|2013-01-01 01:10:00|6.250060498528904 |10.181246688945123|
|2013-01-01 01:20:00|6.254461614739839 |10.18021442155982 |
|2013-01-01 01:30:00|7.0               |20.0              |
|2013-01-01 01:40:00|7.0               |20.0              |
|2013-01-01 01:50:00|7.0               |20.0              |
|2013-01-01 02:00:00|7.0               |20.0              |
|2013-01-01 02:10:00|7.0               |20.0              |
|2013-01-01 02:20:00|6.24546611958182  |10.14886792741417 |
|2013-01-01 02:30:00|6.240802043802097 |10.15267232231782 |
|2013-01-01 02:40:00|6.249921473522189 |10.139161473568803|
|2013-01-01 02:50:00|6.2219054718011515|10.11521891469772 |
|2013-01-01 03:00:00|6.247084671443932 |10.088592826542145|
|2013-01-01 03:10:00|6.24950717588649  |10.065343892142995|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```